# "Reply to this email with 3 available times in the next week" what does it mean in angel list

Tags: recruitment

I have applied to a job in `angel.co`, and I got a match with a response stating that 
`Reply to this email with 3 available times in the next week`

What does it mean and where can I find the 3 available times??

And how to contact the recruiter personally?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's much more about the understanding of English than about the workplace; the answers would be exactly the same if arranging a night out in the pub.

Comment: Of course, if those instructions are difficult, how will the interview go??

Comment: In other words, tell them three time-slots when you'll be available for a (telephonic or otherwise) discussion.

Answer (score 2):

They're asking which 3 times would work for you in the next week.
That way they can pick which of those 3 would also work for them to settle a date for a meeting.

Answer (score 1):

Reply to the email with 3 available times:

1. Monday 09.00 to 09.45
2. Wednesday 11.00 to 11.45
3. Friday 16.00 to 16.45

So define 3 times that work for you and send.